# How to find the first child of a grandparent in XPath for XSLT?

Tags: xslt, xpath

I can’t figure out how to select the first child of a grandparent.

Simple structure:

```
<root>
    <front>
        <div>
            <head>a</head>
            <head>1</head>
        </div>
        <div>
            <head>b</head>
            <head>2</head>
        </div>
    </front>
    <body>
        <div>
            <head>c</head>
            <head>3</head>
        </div>
        <div>
            <head>d</head>
            <head>4</head>
        </div>
    </body>
    <back>
        <div>
            <head>e</head>
            <head>5</head>
        </div>
        <div>
            <head>f</head>
            <head>6</head>
        </div>
    </back>
</root>
```

How to select head **e** with the help of *axes*? I need that for testing inside an XSLT stylesheet, hence the emphasis on axes.

The selection `//head[parent::*[self::div]][1][ancestor::back]` doesn’t work, it still selects both, **e** and **f**.

Comment: what is the context element when you say "*the path .... it still selects both, **e** and **f***" ?

Comment: @HonzaHejzl That makes no sense: which head? And what version of XPath?

Comment: The head **e** is the context node. (As for XPath version, I have no idea, I am simply using the latest stable releases [in XML Oxygen and eXist-db].)

Comment: @HonzaHejzl See here how to find out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25244370/how-can-i-check-which-xslt-processor-is-being-used-in-solr/25245033#25245033 Please make it a habit to state your version when asking about XSLT or XPath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The working solution is a bit tricky (XPath 2.0):

```
//head[count(parent::div[preceding-sibling::div]) < 1 and ancestor::back][1]
```

In the XSLT stylesheet works for me (XSLT 1.0):

```
test=".[count(parent::div[preceding-sibling::div]) &lt; 1 and ancestor::back][1]"
```

**UPDATE**

As shown in comments, there is another one solution, more suitable for XSLT:

```
test=". is ancestor::back/div[1]/head[1]"
```

Comment: **1.** That cannot work in XSLT, because you have an unescaped `<`.  **2.** I believe the test returns true for both `e` and `5` - which is not what you asked for.

Comment: **1.** Ok, changed to `&lt;` in the case for XSLT. **2.** Tested in Oxygen Author 17 as well as XSLT stylesheets for a project generating journal articles from TEI XML, still works ([screen from Oxygen](ftp://46.28.111.241/xpath-sample.jpg)).

Comment: I am not sure what your screenshot is supposed to prove. I suggest you compare http://xsltransform.net/94rmq6Q/1 to http://xsltransform.net/94rmq6Q

Comment: @michael.hor257k, thanks for nice examples (I didn’t know the app). I have two things I want to mention: **1.** I can’t help, my tricky solution still works no matter how hard I try. _Your_ solution is much much better and works for XSLT (but I am not able to reproduce that in Oxygen—that is why I didn’t do it the same way at first). Thanks for that, I will update the answer and mark it. **2.** You seem nicely skilled but too much strict. I don’t want to win something, I am just relatively new to Stack and need some time for learning how to participate. Please, have that on mind.

Comment: **1.** Please refrain from personal remarks. **2.** I am trying to help you the best way I can. It is much more difficult to do when I don't know your purpose. **3.** Try to understand that my time here is limited. I am not trying to win anything, but I may be terse.

Answer (score 0):

From the context of `root`, the following XPath 2.0 expression will select the the first `head` grandchild of  `back`:

```
back/(div/head)[1]
```

To do the same in XPath 1.0, try:

```
back/div[head][1]/head[1]
```

---

### Edit:

> I have the head selected by a stylesheet, now I need to test whether
>   it is the first head of the first div in the back section.

That's a completely different question. From the context of any `head` you can select the first `head` of the first `div` of the current grandparent by:

```
../../div[1]/head[1]
```

Note that this assumes (as does your question) that the first `div` does have a `head` child.

To restrict the scope to only the `back` grandparent, you could use:

```
ancestor::back/div[1]/head[1]
```

Comment: I am sorry, I need that for iteration over `head` element chosen with an XSLT template. That means, I need to use axes, not direct selection downwards.

Comment: I am afraid I have no idea what that means. Every selection uses axes. If you're in the context of root, then the axis can only be child or descendant.

Comment: It is simple, try to do the same starting from the head element upwards. From the top to the bottom it is really simple but in the other direction there are some glitches. I have the head selected by a stylesheet, now I need to test whether it is the first head of the first div in the back section. (I think you know [this](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_axes.asp).)

Comment: I am sorry, misunderstanding. The context node (in the term of my stylesheet **is** the head **e**, which I mentioned in the question.

Comment: @HonzaHejzl I have added an answer to your (new) question. However, I suspect this is an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: Thank you for the moral punch, you are probably right. Sometimes it is a bit difficult to name something properly, mainly when the problem includes more than one technology. I will remember the lesson well. My new answer solves the question. If you would recommend improvements for better readability of the initial question, don’t hesitate and let me know, I want to produce good content here.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the context element is `<head>f</head>`, the following should work:

If you are looking for the first div child of grandparent

```
../../div[1]
```

If you are looking for any child of grandparent

```
../../*[1]
```